# How can I get a key from a List <object> in Firebase in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, firebase-realtime-database, xamarin.forms

I am programming in Xamarin.Forms, I am also using the FirebaseDatabase [dot] net Nuget
I have the following method, in connection to my Firebase Realtime Database, which sends a List.

```
public static async Task<bool> PostDetallePedido(List<AgregarCarrito> carrito)
    {
        try
        {


            var result = await firebase
            .Child("DetallePedidos")
            .Child(Preferences.Get("idOrder", string.Empty))
            .PostAsync(carrito);

            result2 = result.Key;

            var keyTable = new KeyClass()
            {
                keyU = result2,
                orderId = Preferences.Get("idOrder", string.Empty)
            };

            await firebase
            .Child("keyTable")
            .Child(Preferences.Get("idOrder", string.Empty))
            .PostAsync(keyTable);

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"Error:{e}");
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Where my database is filled as follows
[IMAGE 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBxxr.png)

With the previous code I can get the unique-id, but I still don't know how to get the values that are generated in an auto-incremental way

```
-M7B6xMB19uodzf-C71H
| -0
| -1
```

**EDIT:**

```
   public static async Task<List<AgregarCarrito>> GetDetailByUser(int id)
    {
        try

        {
            var key = await GetKey(id);

            var value = (await firebase
            .Child("DetallePedidos")
            .Child(Convert.ToString(id))
            .Child(key.keyU)
            .OnceAsync<AgregarCarrito>()).Select(item =>
            new AgregarCarrito
            {
                orderId = item.Object.orderId,
                ProductName = item.Object.ProductName,
                CustomerId = item.Object.CustomerId,
                Price = item.Object.Price,
                TotalAmount = item.Object.TotalAmount,
                ProductId = item.Object.ProductId,
                Qty = item.Object.Qty,
                imageUrl = item.Object.imageUrl,
                Valor = item.Object.Valor

            }).ToList();

            return value;

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"Error:{e}");
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I have created a method that returns the value of the key using the orderId, but I still cannot access the values of the list, which in this case would be the objects that are generated in an auto-incremental way when sending a List

[IMAGE 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENEas.png)

Comment: you need to provide more detail on your question. it is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: @Daniel You said that the 0 and 1  generate automically? you want to get this key?

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand so far you just want to retrieve the dataset you just inserted before.

```
var postResult = await firebase
        .Child("DetallePedidos")
        .Child(Preferences.Get("idOrder", string.Empty))
        .PostAsync(carrito);

// there is also a `GetAsync` method on your firebase database
var result = await firebase
        .Child("DetallePedidos")
        .Child(Preferences.Get("idOrder", string.Empty))
        .GetAsync(postResult.YOURKEY); // i have no clue how to access the key in your case
```

Comment: I have followed the example you mention, and you can already store the unique id with your example, I can only show the elements that are in that unique id, I have added more information.